# Reflection about a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{3}$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider a symmetric $3\times 3 $ matrix $A$ with $A^2 = I_{3}$. Is the linear transformation $T(\vec{x}) = A\vec{x}$ necessarily the reflection about a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{3}$?

I have a couple of question regarding this problem, the solution manual solved it as follows:

> Yes; if $\vec{v}$ is an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$,then
> $\vec{v}=I_{3}\vec{v}=A^{2}\vec{v}=\lambda^{2}\vec{v}$,so that
> $\lambda^{2}=1$ and $λ=1$ or $\lambda = −1$. Since $A$ is symmetric,
> $E_{1}$ and $E_{-1}$ will be orthogonal complements, so that $A$
> represents the reflection about $E_{1}.$

My question is what if $A^{2}=I_{3}$? is this a reflection? Also, what is the relationship between the eigenvalues being $1$ and $-1$ and the transformation being a reflection? Why is it a reflection?

Also, would there be a different way to solve this problem?

Comment: Do you mean "My question is what if $A=I_3$?"?

Comment: @Arthur Yes. I don't understand if this is a reflection or not, I don't understand how would we use this piece of information $A^{2}=I_{3}$ to figure it out. Do I consider it a reflection?

Comment: $I_3$ can be considered as a reflection, but a "degenerated" one. It would be the reflection w.r.t. the whole space.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Thank you so much. May I also ask why must it be a reflection if the eigenvalues are $1$ and $-1$, what is the relation between eigenvalues and reflections? I am self-studying linear algebra hence why I am a bit confused about some stuff.

Comment: Think of your favorite example of reflection. Let's say that you are in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and you consider the reflection w.r.t. the plane $x=0$. Let $f$ be this reflection. 

You see that all the vectors of the plane are fixed by the reflection (i.e. $f(u)=u$, i.e. they are eigenvectors associated to the eigenvalue $1$). However, vectors that are orthogonal to the plane, for example the vector $(1,0,0)$, are mapped on their opposite (i.e. $f(u)=-u$, i.e. they are eigenvectors associated to the eigenvalue $-1$).

Comment: So the eigenspace associated to the eigenvalue $1$ is exactly the space about which you are doing the reflection ; and it is in direct sum with the eigenspace associated to the eigenvalue $-1$.
And this is the general case. If a diagonalizable mapping has only eigenvalues $1$ and $-1$, then we say that it is the reflection w.r.t. its eigenspace associated to $1$. This definition matches the geometrical idea one can have.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe I understood it clearly now after being stuck for a while. Thank you so much, cleared all my doubts!

Comment: Reflections also need to be orthogonal!